# Extglob pattern match expression "${a//+([0-9])./}" exponentially slow

Tags: bash

Try this (`bash` *v4.4*):

```
a=3.14 ; while true ; do a="$a $a" ; time c="${a//+([0-9])./}" ; echo ${#c} ; done
```

...and type *Control-C* a few times when it gets slow.  Every time the string doubles in length, processing time takes about *10x*.  On my system it takes about 10 seconds for `$c` to become *383* chars long.

Is this slowness a bug?

Comment: This will be faster: `a=3.14; while true; do a="$a $a" ; time sed 's/[0-9]*\.//g' <<< "$a"; done`

Comment: isn't that related to IO from echo

Comment: It looks like `extglob` slows down considerably while handling large string.

Comment: @potato No; removing `echo $c` still leaves a nonlinear slowdown.

Comment: bash is not build for speed

Comment: @anubhava, Using `[[:digit:]]` on my system produces an *8x* time increase per doubled string.  (For this question, the purpose of the code is solely to demonstrate an interesting exponential slowdown.  Please look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373002/stripping-characters-from-a-string/401302#401302) for more efficient code that produces the same sort of output.)